# Display multiple websites in one page jQuery or Ajax or both?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

Here's what I want to do, I have a page right now using iFrames. It is used to manage multiple server switches. Right now, I have multiple links on the left of the page and open each switch page in the iframe on that page.

However, our switch software did a recent update and it won't display the switch page in a frame. We get an error when we try to display it in the iframe. So, we are forced to type the IP address to display the switch page. We have several IT people and would rather have everything in the one page.

I need to have this setup using only 1 page. Can this be done using jQuery and Ajax or can I simply use jQuery to display the switch page in the same page?

thanks in advance, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a Single Page Application (SPA) framework. Other options would be a MVVM framework link AngularJS or Knockout.

Comment: So your DNS is screwed up?

Comment: DNS servers are fine. The only issue is my switch pages will not display in a frame, so I need another option for the page we have setup. I have never used jQuery so, this is new to me. I need to know the code or the easiest way to setup our page. thanks.

Comment: if anyone could help with a solution, I would appreciate it.